# Deploy Project On Elastic Beanstalk and keep running

Tags: eclipse-plugin, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed one webapplication on elastic beanstalk and it's deployed successfully and running. I just wanted to keep it run if I close my eclipse, I investigated regarding this but I didn't find any useful information. Any help will be depreciated.